# Python Optimizer Variable Bound Length

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have an convex function with input vector X of length (variable) T, and have the condition that X_0 = 0. I am trying to set up an optimization function in scipy such that X_0 = 0 don't mind about the rest of the values.

I keep getting the error "length of x0 != length of bounds" when I set up my function with the following bounds

```
bnds = ((0, 0), None)
```

I'm sure the answer is simple, but I haven't figured it out yet. Thanks.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def c(delta):
    x = delta/40
    c = delta*(1/2 * x + np.sign(x)*np.abs(x)**(3/5))
    return c

def u(X):
    return -sum(X[1:] - X[1:]**2 - c(X[1:] - X[:-1]))

T = 30 # user defined variable


bnds = ((0, 0), None)
X = [0]*T
res = opt.minimize(u, X, #method = 'Nelder-Mead',
               bounds = bnds,
               options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'maxiter' : 1e6, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Please, provide proper [mcve] -- e.g. what's `T` set to?

Comment: Please show all your imports as well as the definition of `T`.

Comment: Ok, `X = [0]*T` will give a list of length 30 then, but you pass only two bounds. That's probably the issue then.

Comment: Agreed, but I want to automate the bnds so that if T=40, then it will pass 40 bounds. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited after your last update:

You are passing a sequence of length 2 for the bounds, but the variables you are optimizing over is of length 30.  The bounds parameter has a tuple of length 2 for each variable; using `None` in the tuple means no bound for that end (`-inf` or `inf`).

In your case, you have `(0,0)` for the first variable, and `None` (meaning no bounds) for the second. However, you are passing 30 variables for optimization.

You either need to change your bounds to:

```
bnds = [(0, 0)] + [(None, None)]*29
```

for the case when `T = 30`.

To automate the size of the bounds variable, use:

```
bnds = [(0, 0)] + [(None, None)]*(T-1)
```

Comment: X is a list of length T, and so it needs T bounds. I want to automate the T bounds so that for any T, it passes the bounds (the first of which is x_0 = 0 and the remaining T-1 bounds are (-inf, inf))